# Themes for Presentation with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently tasked with making a plot-heavy presentation. Naturally I am going to prepare all my plots in `ggplot2`. I love Hadley's defaults as they look wonderful both on screen and in print. Typically I also use those defaults for presentations using either a projector or a flatscreen television. However, I was wondering what other options might be out there that would look good in a projection environment? Specifically I was wondering if I might be able to tap into the collective knowledge here to see `theme()` options other people use for presentation purposes when preparing plots with `ggplot2`.

What theme settings are recommended for a presentation with projection?  How do you implement those settings in `ggplot2`?

If there are themes repositories you recommend, I'd also appreciate the reference.

Comment: Lately whenever I present to a client, I try to use their corporate colours in the plot if I can make it look good.  For that, it's often easiest to start with theme_bw() or theme_blank and add things as you see they are needed.

Comment: @CPhil That is actually a fairly useful answer. Why don't you post a simple example of it. People can build off that.

Answer (score 3):

I do actually use this template, changing colors and palettes until I come up with a good set:

```
  plot +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "col1", colour = NA), # or theme_blank()
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white",colour = NA),
    panel.grid.minor = element_line("col2", size = 0.1), 
    panel.grid.major = element_line("col3", size = 0.1)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12, colour="black"),
        axis.title=element_text(size=12,face="bold"))
```

For example:

```
p <- qplot(speed, dist, data=cars)
p +
  geom_point(aes(colour=dist)) + 
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours=rainbow(4)) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#21215f", colour = NA), # or theme_blank()
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white",colour = NA),
    panel.grid.minor = element_line("#736391", size = 0.1), 
    panel.grid.major = element_line("#ecc6d9", size = 0.1)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12, colour="black"),
        axis.title=element_text(size=12,face="bold"))
```

For a better looking grid, the color in `panel.grid.minor` may be closer to the one in `panel.background`. You can change in fact lots of things to get your preferred template.

These links can help:
http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_(ggplot2)
http://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp
http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/themes

[image]

Comment: i do hope you don't actually use rainbow colours

Comment: no, but this could open another entire thread about proper plot coloring.